# How to implement reboot support in TFS autotests?

Tags: tfs, autotest

We're using Microsoft `TFS 2010` autotests in production. I have a lot of tests with mandatory `OS` reboot. When I've tried to automate it, but I faced with the following problem: when virtual machine (`VM`) reboots, `TFS Test Controller` (`TC`) looses connection with `TFS Test Agent` (`TA`) and decides that VM crashes and stops executing **all** remaining tests in current `Test Suite`. These tests became marked as **crashed**.
Is there way to "teach" `TC` and `TA` or entire `TFS` environment to "understand" `VM's` `OS` reboot? E.g. wait to `OS` start for N minutes?
This problem is reported as bug to `MS`, but they won't fix in `TFS 2010`. I don't know about it in `2012` or `2013` versions of `TFS`.
Is there a workaround or a dirty hack?

Comment: Is there a Microsoft Connect issue for this? Or did you get support of MS on your own contract?

Comment: We have reported about it, and MS promised to fix it in `TFS 20112`, but they didn't.